# How to model Beta distribution with Uniform prior in RJAGS?

Tags: r, bayesian, beta-distribution, jags

I'm having trouble modeling a Bayesian problem in RJAGS.

I'm analyzing depth damage curves. In 1988, the US Army Corps of Engineers estimated that 1 foot of flooding would result in 32% mean damage with standard deviation 0.96. The sample size of this estimate is unknown. Therefore I would like to use a Uniform prior of `dunif(0.217, 0.249)`. For a likelihood function, a 2020 paper found that 1-foot of flooding can be better approximated by the beta distribution with `alpha=0.48` and `beta=0.80`, based on sample size ~ 2M. Thus, I would like my likelihood function to be `dbeta(alpha, beta)`.  What would be a good way to factor in the observed `alpha` and `beta` within the likelihood in a JAGS model while still sampling from a distribution? I have my most recent attempt (with no inclusion of observed values in the JAGS model) pasted below:

```
library(rjags)
alpha <- 0.48 # shape
beta <- 0.80 # shape
n <- 10000
a <- 0.217 
b <- 0.249
y <- runif(n, min = a, max = b)

model_string <- "model{
  
  for(i in 1:n){
  
  # Likelihood
  y[i] ~ dbeta(alpha[i], beta[i])
  alpha[i] <- mu[i] * phi
  beta[i]  <- (1-mu[i]) * phi
  mu[i] <- theta
  }
  
  # Prior
  theta ~ dunif(a, b)
  phi ~ dgamma(1,1) 
  a <- 0.217 
  b <- 0.249

}"

dataList <- list(y = y, n = n)
model <- jags.model(file = textConnection(model_string), 
                    data = dataList)

Nrep = 10000 # number of values to simulate
update(model, n.iter = Nrep)


posterior_sample <- coda.samples(model,
                                 variable.names = c("y", "theta", "phi"),
                                 n.iter = Nrep)

summary(posterior_sample)
plot(posterior_sample)
```

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error 
messages, code or packages, etc.) are generally off topic 
here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Oooh sorry about that! Where would be a better place to post? I suppose I can reframe this as a theoretical question about modeling a beta likelihood with a uniform prior...

Comment: ... so then please do so! you can still mention that you plan to use jags ...

Comment: Ok I will shortly thank you